# DHCP Configuration

Tags: windows-server-2003, dhcp

Our network ran out of IP address on the current local subnet, so my boss requested our service provider to change our subnet from /24 to /20, it will give us more than enough IPs to assign to the devices.  Currently there is a DHCP server setup on a Win2k3 server, it is serving IPs to the local network.

Our current IP is 10.10.10.1 to 10.10.10.254, once on /20, it will below 10.10.10.1 to 10.10.15.254.

My question is what or how to implement the /20 on the DHCP server, so that it will serve more than 254 addresses.  For example, if I want from 10.10.10.1 to 10.10.5.254, this will give me enough device IPs, but I'm not sure how to set this up in DHCP.

If I remove the current IP scope and re create a new scope start from 10.10.10.1 and end with 10.10.5.254, will it accept on DHCP?  will my devices obtain IPs from this new scope between this range?

Comment: `If I remove the current IP scope and re create a new scope start from 10.10.10.1 and end with 10.10.5.254, will it accept on DHCP? will my devices obtain IPs from this new scope between this range?` - Yes and Yes. Why wouldn't it work that way?

Comment: I haven't done this before, so I would like some expert suggestions or validating what I am thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you will be able to use the start address and end address detailed in your question as long as you use the appropriate subnet mask of 255.255.240.0 Also take a look at your DHCP server IP address, it might need changing to match your new network.

Comment: thank you.  the server IP is 10.10.10.x and we will manually change all the server subnet mask to 255.255.240.0, will I still need to change the server IP in order to support the DHCP scope above?

Comment: You don't need to change the servers ip address at all, just the subnet mask.

Comment: my mis-type, Joeqwerty is correct changing the mask is all you need.